# How to handle nullable fields for csv generation?

Tags: csv, typescript, export-to-csv

I create from a json source a csv that I want to use to populate a memsql database with the help of `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

I have written a typescript script for the conversation and use the library `json2csv`.

It leaves the values for nulled entries empty though, creating a string like:

```
foo, bar, , barz, 11 ,
```

Yet I expect my output to be:

```
foo, bar, \N , barz, 11 , \N
```

for my nulled fields. Otherwise, my database will fill in different default values, such as `0` for a number that should be `NULL`.

I discovered myself doing:

```
const someEntitites.map((entity: Entity) => {
     entity.foo =  entity.foo === null ? '\\N' : entity.foo;
     entity.bar =  entity.bar === null ? '\\N' : entity.bar;
     ...

     return entity;
}
```

So basically I am hardcoding my approach to my entity, and I also am prone to bug, as I might have forgotten to check a nullable property. And if I am to export another table, I have to repeat this all over again.

How can I generalize this, so I can use this on different entities where the script "discovers" the nullable fields and sets the marker accordingly?

Comment: Can you post details of your `Entity` type?

Comment: @jcalz The specific entity type should be irrelevant. See my own answer.

Comment: Are all the properties in `Entity` possibly null?

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that iterates over its own properties and sets its value to `\N` if the according value is `null`:

```
const handleNullCases = (record: any): any => {
    for (let key in record) {
        if (record.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const value = record[key];
            if (value === null) {
                record[key] = "\\N";
            }
        }
    }

    return record;
};
```

That way I can reuse that snipplet for other entities as well:

```
 const processedEntities = entities.map(handleNullCases); 
 const processedEntities2 = entities2.map(handleNullCases);
 ...
```

I find it a bit dirty, as that I just typehint for `any` and cast the value to a string even though it might have been declared as another type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume all properties in `Entity` may be `null`.  If so, this typing is a bit safer:

```
type Nullable<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] | null};
type CSVSafe<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] | '\\N'};

const handleNullCases = <E>(record: Nullable<E>): CSVSafe<E> => {
  let ret = Object.assign(record) as CSVSafe<E>;
  Object.keys(ret).forEach((key: keyof E) => {
    if (record[key] === null) {
      ret[key] = '\\N';
    }
  });
  return ret;
};

type Entity = Nullable<{ a: number, b: string, c: boolean, d: number, e: string }>;
const entity: Entity = { a: 1, b: null, c: false, d: null, e: 'e' };
const safeEntity = handleNullCases(entity);
// type CSVSafe<{ a: number; b: string; c: boolean; d: number; e: string; }>
```

The `handleNullCases` function will take any object whose values might be `null`, and return a *new* object which is just the same except that `null` values have been replaced with `"\\N"`.  The output type will be a `CSVSafe<>` version of the `Nullable<>` input type.

Hope that helps.